# How do I find the number of grains in this image?

Tags: python, image-processing, count, computer-vision

I'm working on a project and I need to identify the number of grains in pictures with several of these grains touching, overlapping. Can someone help me with this ? Thanks a lot[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Train a model of object detection: You can train some model like object detection (YOLOv5) or some other and calculate the count.

Comment: Did that. Doesn't work when the grains are touching each other. Provides a somewhat accurate result when they are separated.

Comment: Did you had done annotation on Overlapped Data also ? Do that It will Increase the accuracy. @ManasviniSrinivasan

Comment: How did you train Yolov5? Image size, number of images, number of annotations, were there overlapping grains in the data? The task should be easy enough for Yolov5 to handle, IMO

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question so I will give you a broad answer, you could train a computer vision model, or you could use simple image processing using open cv:

- Learn about color threshholding: everything that is not the color of the grain becomes a black pixel, everything else becomes a white pixel.
- Learn about MorphologyEx, to disconnect connected grains.
- Get the numbers of contours of white objects in the blacked out image.

All of those are simple google searches that will achieve what you desire. Using open CV.